# How to display http_build_query result one page to another page using PHP?

Tags: php

I am able to display records on same page but i have to display record one page to another page.I have seen many examples but can't quite get it right though.Would you please help me in this?
   **one.php**

```
$ids = $row["ID"];
$username = $row["Name"];
$search_d = array(
    'id'       => $ids, 
    'username' => $username,
);
$search_details = http_build_query($search_d);
header('Location: index.php?$search_details=1');
```

**second.php**

```
if(!empty($_GET['$search_details'])):
$name = $_GET['$search_details'];
print_r($name);
echo '<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    swal({
        title: "details done",
        type: "success",
        timer: 1500
    });
}, 1000);
</script>';
endif;
```

Comment: I don't think http_build_query does what you think it does...

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to have persistence of `search_details` across pages?

Comment: Thank you for reply Mr.Devon....DO you know other way with session?

Comment: @Hybreeder, of course.  Start the session on both pages, set the session variable on one.php, get the session variable (and possibly clear it) on second.php..

Comment: Or Without session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't concatenate the `$search_details` variable in the argument supplied to `header`.

```
$ids = 1;
$username = 'hassan';
$search_d = array(
    'id'       => $ids, 
    'username' => $username,
);
$search_details = http_build_query($search_d);
header('Location: index.php?' . $search_details);
```

on second page you have to do like that .

```
echo $_GET['id'];
echo $_GET['username'];
```

you dnt need to get search_details variable .
This should work as you expect.

Comment: sure .But currently there only a concatenation issue .So i told him . Thanks for you suggest guys

Comment: Mr.Hassan Ali,I am getting output on URL because of GET.but not getting output on second page.

Comment: simply use $_GET to use these values on second page .

Comment: @Hybreeder Since this answer excluded most of the explanation for why this wasn't working, I added an answer.  My answer and this answer should be able to be used  to solve the problem, however, from what I see, you should not be designing your own code yet.  You still have much learning to do.

Comment: your explanation sucks man @Devon I had provided you solution . thats why you are answering your own question.

Comment: @HassanALi, you realize this isn't my question right?  That should be pretty obvious since I replied  to the OP in my comment...

Comment: Sorry for late reply...Mr.Hassan Ali, I tried your code but my if condition not working because of i used your header code

Comment: why its not working , Do you have any error because  i had test this code .

Comment: There is no error ,Output not displaying on screen.

Comment: had you used exact same code which i had provided in my answer .

Comment: If i used  header code which you provided than  if condition not working and if i used 
header('Location: startEntry.php?search_details=1' . $search_details); then condtion is working but not getting id value.

Comment: you don't need to check the $_GET['search_details'] in your condition .

Comment: Because i am using sweet alert in that if condition you can check my code in question

Comment: i don't think this needed as much you concern about it

Comment: echo $search_details;//getting duplication record username because i set some query
header('Location: xx.php?' . $search_details);

Comment: In above code when pass header section to display record it not display duplicate username also.

Comment: Mr.Hassan Ali, can you help me again.$_GET retrieve only single record but i have multiple records.can you help me in this?please

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin...

**In one.php:**

```
header('Location: index.php?$search_details=1');
```

You're using `$search_details` within single quotes, meaning the variable will not be used.  This will literally be the string `index.php?$search_details=1`.

```
$search_details = http_build_query($search_d);
```

This will build a query string like `ids=value&name=value`.  Thus having a `=1` after it doesn't make any sense.

**In second.php:**

If you correct one.php, you should be able  to access `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['ids']`.  `$search_details` is again in single quotes which makes little sense and that variable has no context in second.php.

---

To me, it seems like you have a lot of learning to do still, you should not be on Stackoverflow or building your own code yet, but reading and following guides.

Comment: Mr.Devon, $_GET displaying only single records in case if we have multiple records than how to display that?